# Yum says dependency " libltdl.so.3" is required, but it's already installed?

Tags: centos, package-management, yum, libraries

I have spent a few hours trying to get ImageMagick installed. I finally got an old version uninstalled, but am struggling to get the newest version installed. When I run the following command:

```
yum --nogpgcheck localinstall ImageMagick-6.9.0-0.i386.rpm
```

I get the following error:

```
Error: Package: ImageMagick-6.9.0-0.i386 (/ImageMagick-6.9.0-0.i386)
           Requires: libltdl.so.3
```

My attempt to get `libltdl.so.3` installed

I ran the following command:

```
repoquery -q -f */libltdl.so*
```

Which produced:

```
libtool-ltdl-0:2.2.6-15.5.el6.i686
yaf-0:1.3.2-1.el6.rf.i686
libtool-ltdl-devel-0:2.2.6-15.5.el6.i686
```

So I tried installing them one by one:

```
yum install yaf-0:1.3.2-1.el6.rf.i686
yum install libtool-ltdl
yum install libtool-ltdl-devel-0:2.2.6-15.5.el6.i686
```

But each one failed with:

```
Package ... installed and latest version
```

What should I do?

I read to try:

```
yum clean all
yum update
```

But that didn't fix the problem. I'm running CENTOS 6.6 i686.

Comment: The operative mantra is 'Don't install an RPM you downloaded manually' unless you know what you are doing. Rebuilding with `fpm` may be safer, yet the best thing is finding the right repo with actively maintained packages.

Comment: And don't try installing packages built for distributions other than the one you're using, which is what it appears you're doing here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on the output, you're mixing i686 and i386 packages together. You need to take care that you have the appropriate archiecture (i386, i686, x86_64, etc.) for your system's hardware and the other packages you have installed.

So in your case `yum` is correctly complaining that you don't have the i386 versions of the dependencies installed already.

```
Error: Package: ImageMagick-6.9.0-0.i386 (/ImageMagick-6.9.0-0.i386)
           Requires: libltdl.so.3
```

So I'd either try getting the i686 version of ImageMagick's RPM or making sure to install the i386 version of the dependencies.

Now given the fact that `repoquery` is only showing i686 packages, I'd surmise that no i386 packages are available in any of the repos you have installed/configured on your system. So I'd likely just download the i686 variant of ImageMagick, since it'll likely be the easiest path forward.

Comment: I'm running I'm running CENTOS 6.6 i686. I asked a question about whether I should install i368 or x86_64 packages on serverfault and was told i368 would work on a i686 machine. Is that not the case? http://serverfault.com/questions/615543/should-i-install-x86-64-or-i386-rpm-packages

Comment: @Nate - Those will work, but the issue is that no repos you have setup are offering them. So I'd go get the i686 version instead.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm confused about which packages you are referring to when you say "those" and "them." Shouldn't the i386 version of ImageMagick be able to be installed on my i686 server?

Comment: @Nate - yeah,however the i386 ImageMagick requires other packages, which have to also be i386. In this case there are none to be found that are i386. So switching to ImageMagick i686 will allow your system to use the i686 versions of the dependencies.

Comment: It's usually wise to not mix architectures (i386, i686, x86_64), for this reason, it can make things more confusing. Unfortunately this is one of those things that you usually miss until it bites you like this, then you learn what it entails.